# Pachico Slim/swoole and Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, eloquent, slim-3, swoole

i have setup the below library:

https://github.com/pachico/slim-swoole

but when I try to run a query with Eloquent ORM I can not, it takes to much time until it gives an error

I understand that I can not use PDO with async framework but how can I have Eloquent ORM working?

Comment: 'Gives an error' What error? what query are you running? Please include all of these when asking future questions. Makes mine and your life easier

Comment: I deleted the framework of my computer searching another solution, but I remebe that it was connection time out. @Isaac in the next question that I will open I will put more information. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PDO with Slim/Swoole but it won't be async, you are right. However, it should all be transparent and you should be able to use ANY ORM with it.